# Kendo UI Ajax not working on production server

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

I am having a problem with KendoUI that works fine in VS2010 when debugging, but the data will not load on the production server.

The controls load fine (I am using some dropdowns and a grid along with some datepicker controls).

Usually, you see a loading animation next to the dropdowns and grid while an AJAX request is sent. I am not getting this on the live server and no AJAX call is being made (I am monitoring traffic with Fiddler).

Can this be a referencing issue? I am copying all DLLs to the production machine (Copy Local) when publishing.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript error on the console when this happens?

Comment: Nope. I am debugging the Javascript in Chrome and getting no errors.

Comment: If you see the call in the Chrome Developer tool, is there some response content coming back, are there the data you are after (network>your call>response tab)? Doesn't sounds like this has anything to do with Kendo !

Comment: Can you add some code, e.g. how you create the dropdown's data source?  Have you tried using jQuery.ajax directly to retrieve the data?